# Do the GoT books also contain nudity?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, adaptation-comparison

In the pilot episode of *Game of Thrones*, when I first saw a prostitute fully undressing in front of the Tyrion, I almost jumped because my mother had just walked past the TV. I proceeded to turn off the TV and swear to always take 18+ notification seriously (Initially, I had thought that 18+ meant extreme violence).

Well, I always wonder why producers and directors go for nudity. I believe everything could be made family friendly without sacrificing any content. For example, prostitutes could be shown from the back like lots of movies and TV shows show. Cersei's naked parade could also be properly depicted by only showing naked legs and upper breast.

Making the show family friendly could also increase the show's audience. Why was it necessary to include nudity in the show? Do the books also contain nudity rejecting which could undermine the show? Any words from producers or directors?

Comment: The show's audience doesn't seem that harmed by it showing nudity, just sayin'

Comment: I don't buy the "why couldn't it be done without nudity?" arguments. They presuppose there is something wrong with nudity. It's okay to make a show not intended for all audiences.

Comment: @cryptarch Nothing's wrong with nudity, but majority of famous TV shows avoid it. That's why I am asking for the reason.

Comment: The books definitely contain nudity, and I could provide examples but I don't know whether this site imposes content filters on its answers.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet Go ahead. Hide the text in spoiler block and add NSFW warning before it.

Comment: Graphic depictions of extreme violence are more "family friendly" / suitable for younger audiences than a little nudity / non-explicit sexuality?

Comment: @SS It's disingenuous to say "hey I'm just asking questions". You've made it clear that you are against nudity on television, by expressing the wish that everything should be made "family friendly". I thus question the validity of the question "Why was it necessary to include nudity in the show?" Perhaps it wasn't _necessary_, but the question is based on a fallacy that everything not necessary should be either justified or excluded.

Comment: A show about incest, murders and rape don't have to be family friendly

Comment: I believe the age old saying "**sex sells**" is reason enough. Not to mention that the adult themes and unfiltered nature is precisely why it has such a huge audience, thus your idea of making it "family friendly" to "increase it's audience" is just backwards to me. If it got rid of all that mature nature it would lose some of it's appeal.

Comment: @ProfesseurDronte Almost all movies and TV shows these days show murder. Rape is also common. Incest shouldn't be seen in bad light especially when it's consensual.

Comment: @cryptarch I didn't say that I am against nudity on television. I didn't say everything should be made family friendly. I said everything "could" be made family friendly. I explored on technical feasibility. Read again.

Comment: The books contain nudity, but it is better timed. I really hated that the show basically expounded on a major character's backstory and motivation (Littlefinger's) during a completely unnecessary nude scene.

Comment: Can I just ask, what's stopping you from picking up the books and reading them to find out for yourself

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The books contain nudity in various scenes but to avoid being overly graphic I’ll just include the one quote.

Note that whilst this quote isn’t overly graphic it also isn’t exactly SFW so discretion is advised.

> It took a long time. All the while he sat there silently, watching her. When she was done, he shook his head, and his hair spread out behind him like a river of darkness, oiled and gleaming. She had never seen hair so long, so black, so thick.
>
> Then it was his turn. He began to undress her.
>
> His fingers were deft and strangely tender. He removed her silks one by one, carefully, while Dany sat unmoving, silent, looking at his eyes. When he bared her small breasts, she could not help herself. She averted her eyes and covered herself with her hands. "No," Drogo said. He pulled her hands away from her breasts, gently but firmly, then lifted her face again to make her look at him. "No," he repeated.
>
> <sub>*A Game of Thrones*, Daenerys II</sub>

GRRM has spoken about the inclusion of nudity in the books and hence it extends to the show to a certain extent. In short he includes it because history has it and not to include it would be hiding the truth and not telling the full story. [Here is one such interview](https://artsbeat.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/05/02/george-r-r-martin-on-game-of-thrones-and-sexual-violence/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=1&) focused on sexual violence but his answer mainly extends to nudity as a whole.

> **Q.** Why have you included incidents of rape or sexual violence in your “Song of Ice and Fire” novels? What larger themes are you trying to bring out with these scenes?
>
> **A.** An artist has an obligation to tell the truth. My novels are epic fantasy, but they are inspired by and grounded in history. Rape and sexual violence have been a part of every war ever fought, from the ancient Sumerians to our present day. To omit them from a narrative centered on war and power would have been fundamentally false and dishonest, and would have undermined one of the themes of the books: that the true horrors of human history derive not from orcs and Dark Lords, but from ourselves. We are the monsters. (And the heroes too). Each of us has within himself the capacity for great good, and great evil.

Comment: I'm disappointed you didn't use the Myrish swamp scene, that would have to the people!

Comment: 'the true horrors of human history derive not from orcs and Dark Lords, but from ourselves. We are the monsters' what a beautiful quote, I wasn't ready for this personal attack!